# Show that a power series is analytic inside its radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, power-series, binomial-theorem

> Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k$ with radius of convergence $R$ then $f$ is analytic on the open disk around $z_0$ with radius $R$.

What I was thinking about is an approach based on this sketch:

[image]

I want to find a new power series based on a new disk with center $\widetilde{z_0}$ and variable $z$. Therefore I am using $z-z_0 = (\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)+(z-\widetilde{z_0})$ which yields

$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\left( (\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)+(z-\widetilde{z_0}) \right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^n(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{k-n}.
$$

I am looking for power series of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-\widetilde{z_0})^k$ but haven't been able to come up with the next step. What is your suggestion based on the method of using the binomial formula (explicitly no derivatives of power series etc. if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two variants. We start with proceeding with your approach.

> Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^k\alpha_{k,n}=\sum_{0\leq n\leq k<\infty}\alpha_{k,n}
> =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty\alpha_{k,n}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> we can write
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^n(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{k-n}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we change the index summation $n \rightarrow k-n$
- In (3) we change the order of summation according to (1)

Another variant could be based upon *[Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition)* expansion.

> Since the Tayler series of $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k$ expanded at $z=\widetilde{z_0}$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}\left(\widetilde{z_0}\right)}{n!}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}\left(\widetilde{z_0}\right)}{n!}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\left.\left(\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k\right)\right|_{z=\widetilde{z_0}}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\left.\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kk(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)(z-z_0)^{k-n}\right)\right|_{z=\widetilde{z_0}}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_kk(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}\right)(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: I have a follow-up question on the first solution especially as I have an exercise which is based on a power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ and $|z_0|<R$ where $R$ is the radius of convergence of $f(z)$. I have to show that for $|z-z_0|<R-|z_0|$ we get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}|a_n||z_0|^{n-k}|z-z_0|^k<\infty$. I could get this expression with my application of the binomial theorem but I don't have an explanation why it converges for $|z-z_0|<R-|z_0|$ - could you give me some suggestions on that one?

Comment: My newest result is that $f(z)$ converges for $|z|<R$ and via the triangle inequality we get $|(z-z_0)+z_0|<R\implies |z-z_0|<R-|z_0|$. Furthermore we know (based on $f(z)<\infty$ for those $z$) that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\binom{n}{k}a_nz_0^{n-k}(z-z_0)^k<\infty$. Thus again via the triangle inequality the absolute value of that sum is $<\infty$ as well.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Please check in your second comment the triangle inequality. It seems to be incorrect $(|(3-6)+6|<7$, but $|3-6|<7-|6|$?. I'm not sure about the precise contents of your exercise.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: A qualitative information: If $f(z)$ can be expanded at $z=z_0$ with radius of convergence $R$ it implies, that the *nearest* singularity or branch point (maybe more than one) of $z_0$ has distance $R$. If we look at some other point $z_1$ and the corresponding radius of convergence when expanding at $z_1$ we have to consider the nearest singularity or branch point with respect to $z_1$ . Since we are typically near to $z_0$ we can often consider the same singularity as that of $z_0$ and apply the triangle inequalities to prove wanted statements.

Comment: I really like your last explanation - at least it is more formal than what I had in mind thus far. What do you think of the addition that we are looking for variables $z$ close to our new center $z_0$ and thus using the triangle inequality holds for those cases? Prosaic: your example would be false in general as your mentioned point $z=3$ wouldn't be in the circle as it is too small since the outer radius isn't allowing it to be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Modify a little using the symmetry of the binomial expansion:
\begin{align}
f(z) & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\left( (\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)+(z-\widetilde{z_0}) \right)^k \\
   & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{k-n}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{n}.
\end{align}
The coefficient of $(z-\widetilde{z_0})^0$ is
$$
       a_0(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^0+a_1\binom{1}{0}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^1+a_2\binom{2}{0}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^2+\cdots
$$
The coefficient of $(z-\widetilde{z_0})^1$ is
$$
    a_1\binom{1}{1}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^0+a_2\binom{2}{1}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^1+a_3\binom{3}{1}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^2+\cdots
$$
Looks like a pattern. The coefficient of $(z-\widetilde{z_0})^{j}$ appears to be
$$
     a_j\binom{j}{j}(z-\widetilde{z_0})^0+a_{j+1}\binom{j+1}{j}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^1+a_{j+2}\binom{j+2}{j}(\widetilde{z_0}-z_0)^{2}+\cdots.
$$